# PostgreSQL: Return DISTINCT rows after a ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql

My Database:

```
SELECT * FROM odds ORDER BY created_at DESC;

 runner_id | value |         created_at         
-----------+-------+----------------------------
    365910 |     5 | 2017-03-13 14:29:45.404927
    365911 |   2.9 | 2017-03-13 14:29:45.404927
    365912 |     7 | 2017-03-13 14:29:45.404927
    365910 |     5 | 2017-03-13 14:29:02.654532
    365911 |     3 | 2017-03-13 14:29:02.654532
    365912 |     7 | 2017-03-13 14:29:02.654532
    365910 |   5.5 | 2017-03-13 14:28:22.733787
    365911 |     3 | 2017-03-13 14:28:22.733787
    365912 |     7 | 2017-03-13 14:28:22.733787
    365910 |   5.5 | 2017-03-13 14:25:42.885042
    365911 |     3 | 2017-03-13 14:25:42.885042
    365912 |   7.5 | 2017-03-13 14:25:42.885042
    365913 |    10 | 2017-03-13 14:25:42.885042
    365910 |     5 | 2017-03-13 14:25:21.842275
    365911 |     3 | 2017-03-13 14:25:21.842275
    365912 |   7.5 | 2017-03-13 14:25:21.842275
    365913 |    10 | 2017-03-13 14:25:21.842275
```

I am looking for the DISTINCT runner_id rows, that have the highest created_at. This is the result I want:

```
 runner_id | value |         created_at         
-----------+-------+----------------------------
    365910 |     5 | 2017-03-13 14:29:45.404927
    365911 |   2.9 | 2017-03-13 14:29:45.404927
    365912 |     7 | 2017-03-13 14:29:45.404927
    365913 |    10 | 2017-03-13 14:25:42.885042
```

It seems dead easy, yet I can't grasp it. I'm starting to think it's not possible because the ORDER BY is what happens last, and I kind of need SQL to ORDER the rows, THEN SELECT DISTINCT on runner_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is a good candidate for using Postgres' analytic function `ROW_NUMBER()`.  You want to retain the latest record among each `runner_id` group of records.  The CTE below computes the row number per this logic, and the query retains only the latest records.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT runner_id, value, created_at,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY runner_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
    FROM odds
)
SELECT
    t.runner_id,
    t.value,
    t.created_at
FROM cte t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

We can also try using `DISTINCT ON` here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (runner_id)
     runner_id, value, created_at
FROM odds
ORDER BY runner_id, created_at DESC
```

Comment: `distinct on ()` is typically faster then using window functions

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not too familiar with `DISTINCT ON`, but I would appreciate your proofreading my updated answer.

Comment: The columns in the on `( ..)` part are not automatically part of the select list, so you need to add `runner_id` to it.